# grpcweb wrapped server functions call via golang client?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-web

I have cloned this project from github : https://github.com/gustavohenrique/grpc-web-golang-vuejs/tree/master/backend.
I ran the project both frontend and backend.It works.
This project is using grpcweb wrapped server.
Then i wrote a small client to call the grpc server functions But it is not working.
My client code looks like this below..

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "time"

    
    pb "backend/proto"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Hello I'm a client")
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("0.0.0.0:9000", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    c := pb.NewAccountServiceClient(conn)
)
    doUnary(c)
}

func doUnary(c pb.AccountServiceClient) {
    fmt.Println("do unary from the client")
    req := &pb.User{
        Email:    "hh1212",
        Password: "23123",
    }

    res, err := c.Create(context.Background(), req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error while calling RPC: %v", err)
    }
    
    log.Printf("Response from Greet: %v", res.GetEmail())

}
```

Now when i run this code it gives me this error back:

```
code = Unavailable desc = connection closed
exit status 1
```

Does grpcweb wrapped server functions like the normal grpc server? or do we have to anything different to communicate from the client side?
golan

Comment: have you tried to use https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui? if the grpcUI is able to connect to the server, you will know that the problem is not on the server side.